# Present Perfect (to keep a diary)

Tags: present-perfect

Sentence:

> I've kept a diary for twelve years now.

It means I began to do it in the past, continued up doing it and I'm doing it now, doesn't it?

Comment: You *began* to keep it in the past and you have been keeping it all along.

Comment: Present Perfect doesn't *always* imply "still doing it". For example, if I say *I've given up smoking three times now*, this implies nothing about whether I'm *currently* abstaining. All I'm implying is that the fact of me having done this in the past is somehow ***relevant to time of speaking***.

Comment: Why not use the Present Perfect Continuous? **I have been keeping a diary**

Comment: ...note that it's perfectly credible to say *I have kept a daily diary for months at a time when I was younger, but these days I only write something once or twice a week.*

Comment: I'm confused about the verb **keep**. Don't we usually **run a diary**?

Comment: @SovereignSun, sure. "keep" isn't a stative verb.

Comment: No we don't "run a diary", at least not in this sense.

Answer (score -2):

It means you were doing it in the past, and kept on doing it up to about now, and may or may not be doing it now. The period of 12 years referred to is the 12 years up to the present moment.

The present perfect progressive, **have been keeping** would be basically the same meaning, the choice would be stylistic.

Comment: what do you mean by "stylistic" in this case

Comment: @user5577 That there is no real difference in meaning, but as a matter of style one might prefer one over the other.

Comment: No, it implies you are still doing it. No doubt about it.